# Spring project redundant classes

Tags: java, spring

I'm building a SpringMVC project for the first time and just wanted some feedback on my design.

At the moment I have the following UserDao

```
package org.myproj.com.dao;

import org.myproj.com.entity.User;

public interface UserDao {
    public User getById(Long id);
}
```

This is implemented by the UserDaoImpl

```
package org.myproj.com.dao;

import org.myproj.com.entity.User;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public User getById(Long id) {
        return (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
    }

}
```

I then have a service layer, UserService

```
package org.myproj.com.service;

import org.myproj.com.entity.User;

public interface UserService {
    public User getById(Long id);
}
```

With an impl, UserServiceImpl

```
package org.myproj.com.service;

import org.myproj.com.dao.UserDao;
import org.myproj.com.entity.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;


    public UserServiceImpl() {
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getById(Long id) {
        return userDao.getById(id);
    }

}
```

This is then accessed by my servlet with...

```
@Autowired
    private UserService userService;

User user = userService.getById(1L);
```

I can't help but feel that my Dao and my Service are replicating a lot.  I'm considering using the service layer to add stuff like roles etc and the Dao do the business logic.

What do you think of this design?  Is it acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO it's best to put the semantics of the business transactions into the service layer, and the data-side building blocks into the dao layer. The dao layer is then the data API used by the services. So, while the dao layer might have `UserDao` with a `findByName(String username)` method, the service layer wouldn't. Instead, the service layer would have a `SecurityService` with a `authenticateUser(String username)` and that would, among other things, call `userDao.findByName(username)`. And if you have a `UserDetailService` with a `addEmailAddressToUser(String username)`, well, that would call the same dao method.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it looks a bit repetitive when you're showing a simple example, but once your service layer starts getting more complicated (coordinating multiple services/DAOs) and your DAOs have more complicated queries, the separation of business logic and data access logic will start to make more sense...

The service and DAO interfaces won't always look so similar. One should be a coarser-grained and transaction based while the other is based around entities and database queries.